# ¿Como subir una aplicacion mean a heroku?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, mongodb, heroku

Realice una aplicación de encuesta y me gustaría publicarla pero he tenido algunos problemas.

Aquí les muestro la estructura de mi aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui muestro el backend de mi aplicación en nodejs este es el app.js

```js
// Require
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// inicializar variables
var app = express();

//body parser 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/sistem-encuesta'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/sistem-encuesta/index.html'));
  });

//importar rutas 
var appRuta = require('./rutas/app');
var usuarioRuta = require('./rutas/usuarios');
var loginRuta = require('./rutas/login');
var sidebarRuta = require('./rutas/sidebar');
var reporteRuta = require('./rutas/reporte');
var GenEncuestaRuta = require('./rutas/genEncuesta');
var DatosEncuestaRuta = require('./rutas/DatosEncuesta');


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")
    next();
  });

//conecxion a la base de datos



mongoose.connection.openUri('mongodb://localhost:27017/encuestas', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true
}, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Database conection: \x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'ONLINE');
})


// Rutas 
app.use('/',appRuta);
app.use('/usuario',usuarioRuta);
app.use('/login',loginRuta);
app.use('/sibebar',sidebarRuta);
app.use('/reporte',reporteRuta);
app.use('/genEncuesta',GenEncuestaRuta);
app.use('/datosEncuesta',DatosEncuestaRuta);
app.listen(port,()=>{

    console.log('express server puerto 3000 online :D'+port)

});
```

Errores en el heroku al tratar de ejecutar open heroku,desde mi punto de vista tengo algo man en el backend.
llevo ya un buen rato tratatan de ver, viendo foros y nada todavia, una ayuda me vendría realmente bien

```js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180353+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180354+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180354+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180355+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180356+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180356+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180357+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180357+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180357+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180358+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
2020-05-30T21:50:54.180359+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
2020-05-30T21:50:54.181016+00:00 app[web.1]: See "/tmp/ng-IW9SZT/angular-errors.log" for further details.
2020-05-30T21:50:54.190099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-30T21:50:54.190491+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-30T21:50:54.190773+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-30T21:50:54.191062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-30T21:50:54.192284+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2020-05-30T21:50:54.192439+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-30T21:50:54.192633+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-30T21:50:54.192792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start script.
2020-05-30T21:50:54.192922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-30T21:50:54.202309+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T21:50:54.202526+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-30T21:50:54.202678+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-30T21_50_54_193Z-debug.log
2020-05-30T21:50:54.259116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-30T21:50:54.297686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-30T22:08:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gabrielhernandezgjha1@gmail.com
2020-05-30T22:14:45.781290+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user gabrielhernandezgjha1@gmail.com
2020-05-30T22:14:45.781290+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4adf7bea by user gabrielhernandezgjha1@gmail.com
2020-05-30T22:14:46.310536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-30T22:14:58.798430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-05-30T22:15:01.821426+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:01.821446+00:00 app[web.1]: > sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start /app
2020-05-30T22:15:01.821447+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2020-05-30T22:15:01.821447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463925+00:00 app[web.1]: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463977+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463979+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463980+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463980+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463981+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463982+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463982+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463982+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463983+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463983+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463984+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
2020-05-30T22:15:03.463984+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
2020-05-30T22:15:03.464602+00:00 app[web.1]: See "/tmp/ng-wiRxjj/angular-errors.log" for further details.
2020-05-30T22:15:03.483369+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-30T22:15:03.483611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-30T22:15:03.483948+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-30T22:15:03.484275+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:15:03.485800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2020-05-30T22:15:03.485997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:15:03.486233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-30T22:15:03.486459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start script.
2020-05-30T22:15:03.486649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-30T22:15:03.501535+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:03.502328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-30T22:15:03.502836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-30T22_15_03_487Z-debug.log
2020-05-30T22:15:03.566686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-30T22:15:03.621369+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-30T22:15:03.623941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-30T22:15:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-30T22:15:12.596030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-05-30T22:15:15.099453+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:15.099473+00:00 app[web.1]: > sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start /app
2020-05-30T22:15:15.099473+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2020-05-30T22:15:15.099473+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157569+00:00 app[web.1]: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157581+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157582+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157584+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157584+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157584+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157585+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157585+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157586+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157586+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157586+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157587+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
2020-05-30T22:15:16.157587+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
2020-05-30T22:15:16.158038+00:00 app[web.1]: See "/tmp/ng-bIHdKJ/angular-errors.log" for further details.
2020-05-30T22:15:16.166703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-30T22:15:16.166994+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-30T22:15:16.167213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-30T22:15:16.167446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:15:16.168447+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2020-05-30T22:15:16.168585+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:15:16.168750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-30T22:15:16.168898+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start script.
2020-05-30T22:15:16.169024+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-30T22:15:16.176446+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:15:16.176616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-30T22:15:16.176727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-30T22_15_16_169Z-debug.log
2020-05-30T22:15:16.230021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-30T22:15:16.264795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-30T22:15:18.954608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=api-rest-encuestas.herokuapp.com request_id=c5bfa4dc-70e9-4d0f-9329-0b48997a5ecd fwd="190.141.143.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-30T22:15:19.109472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=api-rest-encuestas.herokuapp.com request_id=8a4bb288-6296-414f-96b3-0128cdd2de11 fwd="190.141.143.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-30T22:36:00.481161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-30T22:36:10.281620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-05-30T22:36:13.082696+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:36:13.082722+00:00 app[web.1]: > sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start /app
2020-05-30T22:36:13.082723+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2020-05-30T22:36:13.082723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284001+00:00 app[web.1]: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284038+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284041+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284042+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284042+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284043+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284044+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284044+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284044+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284044+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284045+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284045+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284046+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
2020-05-30T22:36:14.284844+00:00 app[web.1]: See "/tmp/ng-2d8Tc9/angular-errors.log" for further details.
2020-05-30T22:36:14.297524+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-30T22:36:14.297734+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-30T22:36:14.297877+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-30T22:36:14.298036+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:36:14.299005+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2020-05-30T22:36:14.299096+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-30T22:36:14.299215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-30T22:36:14.299306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the sistem-encuesta@0.0.0 start script.
2020-05-30T22:36:14.299372+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-30T22:36:14.304333+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-30T22:36:14.304487+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-30T22:36:14.304565+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-30T22_36_14_300Z-debug.log
2020-05-30T22:36:14.355210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-30T22:36:14.392799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

```js
{
  "name": "sistem-encuesta",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.13.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~12.16.1",
    "npm": "~6.13.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Procura añadir el error en texto, no en imagen, para que sea más sencillo de leer y se te pueda ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Listo. ya corregi

Comment: comparte como lo solucionaste, así puede que le sirva a alguien mas.

Comment: Lo solucionaste? Tengo este problema